# Sorting a partially linked list in sql

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I have declared a task-priority list in SQL like so:

```
CREATE TABLE TaskList(
    id int not null primary key,
    execute_before int null,
    SomeData nvarchar(50) NOT NULL)
```

I now want to select rows from this table such that the rows would be sorted by id, but any rows that "execute_before" a given row would be placed before such rows, again sorted by id.

So, if the table contains data like this:

```
id      execute_before
1       null
2       null
3       2
4       3
5       2
6       null
```

the result should be like so:

```
id      execute_before
1       null
4       3
3       2
5       2
2       null
6       null
```

My target SQL server is PostgreSQL, but I'm using it through Django, so either of these solutions is fine.

I'm currently solving the issue with a rather inefficient (gross understatement) sorting in code:

```
def annotate_exec_sort(queryset):
    from functools import cmp_to_key
    from django.db.models import Case, When

    def cmp(item1, item2):
        rb = item1.run_before
        while rb:
            if rb.id == item2.id:
                return -1
            rb = rb.run_before
        rb = item2.run_before
        while rb:
            if rb.id == item1.id:
                return 1
            rb = rb.run_before

        if item1.id < item2.id:
            return -1
        elif item1.id > item2.id:
            return 1
        return 0

    recs = sorted(queryset.all(), key=cmp_to_key(cmp))
    return queryset.annotate(srt=Case(*[When(id=r[1], then=r[0]) for r in enumerate([r.id for r in recs])],
                                      default=0,
                                      output_field=models.IntegerField()))
```

Comment: How do you know there are no cycles?

Comment: I don't. It's only the logic during inserts that takes care of that

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using PostgreSQL WITH RECURSIVE query to traverse the
dependency graph. The setup looks like this:

```
begin;

drop table if exists tasklist;

create table tasklist
(
    id int not null primary key,
    execute_before int null
);

\copy tasklist(id, execute_before) from stdin with csv delimiter E'\t' null as 'null'
1   null
2   null
3   2
4   3
5   2
6   null
\.

commit;
```

And then the solution looks like the following:

```
with recursive s as
(
    select id, execute_before, 0 as level, '{}'::integer[] as before
      from tasklist t1
     where execute_before is null

 union

    select tasklist.id,
           tasklist.execute_before,
           level + 1 as level,
           case when tasklist.execute_before is not null
                then before || tasklist.id
                else before
            end as before
      from tasklist
           join s
             on tasklist.execute_before = s.id
     where not tasklist.id = any(before)
)
  select id, execute_before, level, before
    from s
order by level desc, id;
```

which gives the following output:

```
 id │ execute_before │ level │ before 
════╪════════════════╪═══════╪════════
  4 │              3 │     2 │ {3,4}
  3 │              2 │     1 │ {3}
  5 │              2 │     1 │ {5}
  1 │              ¤ │     0 │ {}
  2 │              ¤ │     0 │ {}
  6 │              ¤ │     0 │ {}
(6 rows)
```

Comment: While a good effort, it doesn't give the correct result: records with execute_before are not automatically promoted to the top of execution list. They are only promoted before their given execute_before records.